# Why am i getting garbage in total for array?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

I initialized array to 0's. When I walk thru debugger I get garbage in the [5][4] element. The variable that stores value is emp4tot. I am getting the total for each employee sales. Each product is  represented by a row there are five different products. The columns represent the four employees. I am totaling the
sales of all employees by summing each column.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

void printtot(float[5][4], int, int);

int main()
{
using namespace std;
float sales[5][4] = { 0.0 };
int prodnum, empnum;
float prodtot=0;
const int numemp = 4;
const int numprod = 5;

/*do{

    cout << "Enter Employee Number" << endl;
    cin >> empnum;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Enter Product Number" << endl;
    cin >> prodnum;
    cout<< endl;
    cout << " Enter Product Sales" << endl;
    cin >> prodtot;
    cout << endl;

    if ((empnum > 0) && (empnum < 5)){
        --prodnum;
        sales[prodnum][empnum] = prodtot;
    }

    }while ((empnum > 0) && (empnum < 5));

*/      
    printtot(sales, numemp, numprod);



    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(255, '/n');
    cin.get();

    return 0;
}

  void  printtot(float salesarry[5][4],int numberempl, int numberprod){
    using namespace std;
    float product_tot;
    float employee_tot;
    float emp1tot, emp2tot, emp3tot, emp4tot;
    int i, j;

employee_tot = product_tot = emp1tot = emp2tot = emp3tot = emp4tot = 0.0;

cout << "\t"<<"\t"<<"\tEmp 1" << "\tEmp 2" << "\tEmp 3" << "\tEmp 4"<< endl;

        for (i = 0; i < numberprod; ++i){
        product_tot = 0;
        cout << "\t" << "Product " << i + 1;
        for (j = 1; j < numberempl; j++){
            cout <<"\t"<<salesarry[i][j];
            product_tot += salesarry[i][j];
        }
        cout << "\t" << product_tot << endl;
        emp1tot += salesarry[i][1];
        emp2tot += salesarry[i][2];
        emp3tot += salesarry[i][3];
        emp4tot += salesarry[i][4];
    }

cout <<"\tEmployee Totals"<<"\t"<<emp1tot<<"\t"<<emp2tot<<"\t"<<emp3tot <<
       "\t" << emp4tot << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Arrays are indexed from zero. Hence:

```
float sales[5][4];
```

has no index `[5][4]`. The first element of the first array in sales is `sales[0][0]`. The "last" element is `sales[4][3]`.

Answer (score 2):

You declared `float sales[5][4]`.

There is no `[5][4]` element in that array. The maximum is `sales[4][3]`. The elements start from zero, so the last element has an index one less than the size of the array. The first element is `sales[0][0]`.

Comment: OK thanks was thinking rows index started at 1 instead of zero!

Answer (score 2):

You used 1-based array indexes in printtot, here:

```
emp1tot += salesarry[i][1];
emp2tot += salesarry[i][2];
emp3tot += salesarry[i][3];
emp4tot += salesarry[i][4];
```

Those should be:

```
emp1tot += salesarry[i][0];
emp2tot += salesarry[i][1];
emp3tot += salesarry[i][2];
emp4tot += salesarry[i][3];
```